# Can install Payara server multiple versions on Linux box

Tags: linux, payara

I have payara server (v4) installed and running Linux (Centos). Now I want to install payara 5 also on same box.
I installed payara5 created new domain, but getting exception while running the newly created domain
Does it possible to have 2 version of payara running on same Linux box?

Comment: did you configure a different port for the second Payara? Both can't run on `8080`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but they must be configured to run using different ports.

Changing the ports used can be done in the admin console by going to to Configurations->server-config->HTTP Service->HTTP Listeners then altering the port for each of the listeners so they are not identical for the two domains.

Alternatively use the asadmin commands

`set configs.config.server-config.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.${network-listener-name}.port=value`

to change the value of each network listener. `list-http-listeners` is the command to list what the names of all the listeners are.

Note that once the admin listener is changed the admin console will be on the new port, not 4848; and also that asadmin commands must specify the port with `-p ${port-value}` to send commands the domain that is not on 4848.